# Aggregation is too slow on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch, i have more than 25 million of data in elasticsearch index on a single node cluster, when i do aggregation query it takes a lot of time and even get timeout. I think I'm doing something wrong here.

```
ES INFO:
nodes: 1,
primary-shards: 30,
replica-shards: 30,
total index size: 90gb,
each shards holding 3gb of data,

SYSTEM INFO:
250 SSD ram 28GB
```

Comment: Can you add mapping of you index? and query you are running?

Comment: {
 "query": {
            "simple_query_string": {
              "query": "search text"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "popular_authors": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "AuthorList.Name.keyword"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "articles": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "ArticleTitle.keyword"
                  },
                
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "size": 1
        }

Comment: mapping looks similar to this

{
  articleTitle: 'somet title',
  authorList: [{'Name':'author1}, {'Name':'author2'}],
  abstract: 'article abstract goes here.......................................'
}

Comment: If you can please update question description so that JSON is formatted. Also please add mapping description like GET index/_mapping

Comment: @luka can you pls tell me that my system configuration above is ok or not for that much data.

Comment: i also need to do lot of analysis on large data in realtime.

Comment: I think because you are doing aggregation over text data and you have 10m documents it will be slow but I need to see config of elastic, mapping of index and query to understand what is problem. For example if you have analyzer on each field and you do aggregation and text is large it can be really slow so maybe by somehow changing how you store or map stuff you can improve speed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171871/discussion-between-arun-arumugam-and-luka-lopusina).